# Using $_GET to echo special characters from an URL

Tags: php

I am working on a school project and am quite new to php so pardon me if this may come off as sounding stupid.

I am trying to use $_GET to fill in a form with the information that was previously inputted into the fields when the user has somehow ran into a problem like leaving fields empty and was forced back into the form web page.

One of the fields may require the user to input operands on mathematical problems (ie. 1+1=2) but when echo-ing back the result the "+" sign is replaced with a space.

```
<input id="register" name="enun" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question *" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['error'])){echo $_GET['enun'];}?>" />
```

The link "(...).php?error=equalquestion&enun=**1+1=?**&resp=2(...)" and I want to echo the bolded part.

I have tried some other fixes around stackoverflow like "htmlentities" / "htmlspecialchars" / "urldecode" but to no avail.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A raw `+` in a URL **is** a space. It needs escaping if you want to express a plus symbol. the problem is with how the URL is generated, not with what you are doing with it in the script it points to.

Comment: Use `urlencode()` in PHP when creating URL parameters. In JavaScript use `encodeURIComponent`. This is normally handled automatically by the browser when submitting a form.